# Play framework 1.x render with url fragment

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to render a view and append a fragment to the url?

I think of something like:

```
http://controller/action#tab1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript for this:

window.location.href=@{action}/tab1

Comment: Ok I admit that the question wasn't exactly what I was looking for- I was looking for a way to store the active tab (#tab1) and redirect to it after a server request. I solved this problem using the session now.